# Why is my animation "replayed" when an element is added via innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, innerhtml

I have a little script that adds a div named "doge" using `innerHTML` when clicking on a button on my page, and on this page there's a div with a CSS keyframes animation.

However, when I click on the button to add the div named "doge" on my page, the CSS animation is "replayed". Why? How can I fix that?

```js
function addHtml() {
    document.getElementById("wow").innerHTML += '<div class="doge">such wow</div>';
}
```

```css
@keyframes color {
    10% {
        background: #4CAF50;
    }
    50% {
        background: #3F51B5;
    }
    100% {
        background: #009688;
    }
}

.myDiv {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    animation: color 1s;
}

.doge {
    background: #F57F17;
}
```

```html
<div id="wow">
    <div class="myDiv">Hi!</div>
    <br>
    <button onclick="addHtml()">Add HTML!</button>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mvu8g8tn/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you're modifying all of the element's HTML when you modify the `.innerHTML` property.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> `.innerHTML` - Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.

In doing so, the DOM assumes that the `.myDiv` element has just been added which means that the animation is going to be replayed. To work around that, use the [`.appendChild()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) instead:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/32kjxkfp/)

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = 'such wow';
div.className += 'doge';
document.getElementById("wow").appendChild(div);
```

---

Alternatively, as [Teemu points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401219/why-does-css-keyframe-animation-is-replayed-when-an-element-is-added-with-ja/34401259?noredirect=1#comment56545547_34401259), you can also use the [`.insertAdjacentHTML()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML):

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/dfc6xtgj/)

```
document.getElementById("wow").insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div class="doge">such wow</div>');
```

Comment: @MrZrn See the link in my answer.

Comment: working, but there's no solution to directly add my html code ? like innerHtml ?

Comment: @MrZrn [Actually there is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), but I'd still prefer Josh's code as a primary method to add content to a page.