# add event not working properly with closure in a loop

Tags: javascript

The practical problem I've met is just like the testing code below

I need to pack the bunch of event adder in a function, and call it many times

It generate the same result, that is, the event not applying to every element

```
window.onload = function() {
  var body = document.body;
  var elText = '<input id="randId" type="text"/>';
  var elTmp;
  var ids = [];
  var times = 3;
  var randId = function(){
    return Math.random().toString(36).substr(2,9);
  };
  var setEvent = function(el, text) {
    el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      el.value = text;
    });
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    ids.push(randId());
    body.innerHTML += elText.replace('randId', ids[ids.length - 1]);
    elTmp = document.getElementById(ids[ids.length - 1]);
    setEvent(elTmp, 'this is ' + (i+1));
  }
};
```

Even wrap those code in a closure, the event only apply to the last created element, the first two are not

Refer to this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177757/javascript-multiple-dynamic-addeventlistener-created-in-for-loop-passing-param)

```
  for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    ids.push(randId());
    body.innerHTML += elText.replace('randId', ids[ids.length - 1]);
    elTmp = document.getElementById(ids[ids.length - 1]);
    (function(_i) {
      setEvent(elTmp, 'this is ' + (_i+1));
    })(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that all of the inner HTML is changing on each iteration. When this happens, all of the previous event listeners are removed (since the elements are removed from the DOM). I just answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401219/why-is-my-animation-replayed-when-an-element-is-added-via-innerhtml/34401259#34401259) earlier.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML):

> `.innerHTML` - Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.

To work around that, you could use the [`.insertAdjacentHTML()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to insert the element instead. In doing so, none of the other HTML is touched/removed since this merely *inserts* the HTML.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/61v62jnn/)

```
for (var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
  ids.push(randId());
  body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', elText.replace('randId', ids[ids.length - 1]));
  elTmp = document.getElementById(ids[ids.length - 1]);
  setEvent(elTmp, 'this is ' + (i+1));
}
```

Of course, you can also use the [`.appendChild()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) as well.

Comment: Christ! You are my hero!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `innerHTML`, the content of body is **overwrited** again and again, the `Event Listener` is removed again and again.
I think you should use like `$('').append()` method in `Jquery` to add `Element`.

Answer (score 0):

For solution, [Josh Crozier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2680216/josh-crozier)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34407675/5645769) has already. I only want to explain a bit why JS is removing your previous event handlers while your previous html is being kept as you are using `+=` for appending the html. Have a closer look at this :

```
body.innerHTML += elText.replace('randId', ids[ids.length - 1]);
```

It's actually a shortcut of the following :

```
body.innerHTML = body.innerHTML + elText.replace('randId', ids[ids.length - 1]);
```

So, at first you are getting `body.innerHTML` which is only a text string, there is no event handler bound to it and you are appending your new text with it, after that you are setting that as `body.innerHTML`. In that time it works as [Josh Crozier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2680216/josh-crozier) highlighted :

> `.innerHTML` - Removes all of element's children, parses the content string and assigns the resulting nodes as children of the element.